# Extracting data from multiple pages

Tags: html, screen-scraping, extract

I have found some data I would like to extract (http://www.education.gov.uk/edubase/public/quickSearchResult.xhtml?page=1) however there is 1080 pages I would need to scrape, does anyone know a way of scraping multiple pages for their `<table>` elements?

Comment: any preference on the language? Scrapy is a nice framework in Python for this kind of scraping (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Preferably PHP but it doesn't really matter as long as I can get the data

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to try IRobotSoft web scraping.  It is at free and provides visual interfaces.  Check out the demo at http://www.irobotsoft.com/help/ first.  Their forum is very helpful as well.